# Permutations of string counting a group of characters as a single unit

Tags: php, algorithm, combinations, permutation

My Question may sound noob but here it goes.

I take an input from the user as "Karim@123". I want my Program to create the permutations of the given input treating "Karim", "@" and "123" as single individual units.So the output will be something like "karim123@", "@karim123", "@123karim","123@karim","123karim@". Remember there will be 3! permutations in this particular  case. I am using a php function but that function tells me all the permutations of "karim@123" which is not what i want. The function is as follows.

```
function permute($str,$i,$n) {
   if ($i == $n)
       print "$str\n";
   else {
        for ($j = $i; $j < $n; $j++) {
          swap($str,$i,$j);
          permute($str, $i+1, $n);
          swap($str,$i,$j); // backtrack.
       }
   }
}

// function to swap the char at pos $i and $j of $str.
function swap(&$str,$i,$j) {
    $temp = $str[$i];
    $str[$i] = $str[$j];
    $str[$j] = $temp;
}   
$str = "hey";
permute($str,0,strlen($str));
```

PS : I am new to programming and algorithms.

PPS: Please, specify reason before downvoting.

Comment: Why do you make only 3 divisions of the string like `Karim`, `@` and `123` and why not 4 or 5 or 2 or `k` divisions?

Comment: Is it so that you group the strings in groups that include all alphabetical characters together, all special characters together and all numbers together?

Comment: Exactly. Moreover the pattern of the input string will be like this.

"word"+"special character"+"digits".

Comment: I've written an answer then. It is kind of trivial approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the way you divide the string is that you include all alphabetical characters together, all special characters together and all numbers together, you can create a map like this for above example:

```
A => Karim
B => @
C => 123
```

Then create all permutations of "ABC", which will be:

```
ABC, ACB, BAC, BCA, CAB, CBA
```

and replace with the corresponding values from the map.

Comment: "to some extent"? You have other doubts/problems? Feel free to ask, I'll try and help in best way I can.